# How do you use Github Workflows to un-zip an archive sitting on an Azure Web App Service?

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I have a react/node app that I'm deploying through Github Workflow to a linux/node Azure Web App service.

I zip up the artifact in the build step (to speed up the build). Then in the deploy step, I unzip the archive and deploy it using azure/webapps-deploy@v2.

The deploy is over 10,000 files and it takes a long time - 10 minutes. To speed it up, I'd like to deploy the zip archive to my site, then un-pack the archive ON THE SERVER. So that I don't have to transfer a gazillion files.

How would I go about doing this?

Here's my workflow:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: build client
        env: 
          VITE_API_URL: "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net"
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: build server
        run: |
          cd server
          npm install
          cd ..

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App' #This takes forever b/c there are over 10k files.
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'myapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: .
```

Comment: `zip release.zip ./* -r` is compressing everything including your two node_modules, are you sure that you want to ship that?

Comment: Would you recommend I `npm install` during the deployment step so I don't have to copy node_modules from the build step? Or are you saying I should call `npm install` on server start-up? Or should I just copy my source code up to the server and SSH to `npm install`? I'm just not sure if there's a best way of doing it. But the way I've got it is just taking too long.

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure, but if I would deploy an app with Node.js I would either do `npm i` on the server or if I had to do it on the pipeline I would do just `npm i --production` for the front-end, if it's a client-side rendered app I'd just copy the build/dist folder w/o node_modules or the source code in that zip.

Comment: You make a good point - for the front-end I guess I don't need node_modules, but for the back-end node app, I do.